# Is it legal for my school to not have nutrition facts?

Tags: pediatrics, health-education, legal, nutrition, public-awareness

At my Connecticut school, at went up to the lunch lady and asked her for the nutrition facts. They did not have them. I found a few of the nutrition facts online on the school website, but many nutrition facts were missing. Is this legal?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [it is a legal question](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/47/2192).